# Duda con cotejamiento de mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy armando una parte de la página donde voy a mostrar breves "noticias" que se van a ir cargando por los administradores de la página. Estoy usando la base de datos de MySQL y tengo algunas dudas en cuanto al "cotejamiento" y la posibilidad de que pueda guardar los datos completos: acentos, "ñ", etc...

Por el momento la tengo seteada en latin1_swedish_ci.

Una de las dudas que tengo es si coloco un textarea para escribir la nota y después guardo los datos, ¿cómo se comporta lo que puse en la base de datos? ¿Conserva los saltos de linea?

Comment: por que no antes de guardar con php no ejecutas una funcion de parseo a html y te despreocupas de esto?

Comment: ah, dices que pase a &aacute; etc y grabo ese resultado...

Comment: exacto html_entities_encode y decode, html_special_char estas funciones son propias de PHP

Comment: genial !!! buena idea !!! gracias Jack

Comment: Por favor no apliques la recomendación de @JackNavaRow , es esta totalmente desaconsejado. Además ¿por qué poner un parche cuando puedes hacer las cosas bien?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

les comento a todos que **No es una buena práctica** almanecar 
 información como: á imagenes, etc, jamas lo hagan, para eso existe el UTF-8, y lo pueden implementar de la siguiente manera:

> WEB (HTML) ---> CLIENTE

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> MYSQL ---> BASE DE DATOS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en al base de datos la información quedaría grabada de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo correcto, espero haberte ayudado, saludos.

> PHPMYADMIN

Si usas PDO para las conecciones a base de datos, puedes usar esta sentencia para mandar el contenido utf8 a la base de datos.

```
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $server . ';dbname=' . $db . ';charset=UTF8', $user, $pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

Comment: No se si será por el workbench pero ese tipo de cotejamiento "default collation" no existe en PHPMyAdmin... una vez me pasó con herramientas para manejar bases de SQLite que algunas me permitían operaciones que otras no (no viene al caso comentar que cosas si y que cosas no)... a lo que voy es que quizás ese programa que usas te deja definir ciertas cosas que el otro no. Pero en PHPMyAdmin tengo "utf8_unicode_ci", "utf8_general_ci" y "utf8_spanish_ci"...

Comment: tomando en cuenta tu opinion, modificare, mi respuesta

Comment: Solo un apunte. Para bases de datos mysql la recomendación es utilizar **utf8mb4** .